# ASP.NET User control with ASP:CreateUserWizard

Tags: asp.net, controls

When using asp:login, asp:forgotpassword and asp:createuserwizard controls within an ascx. (e.g registration.ascx) it can't find e.g UserName, even though it exists within LayoutTemplate. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

If you open smart tag for control in design mode,you shall see that there are steps that can be convertible to templates for customization.

[CreateUserWizard http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/3823/7d4df5a594a1abdb8fdc8f1.png](http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/3823/7d4df5a594a1abdb8fdc8f1.png)

For CreateUserWizard , press **Customize Create User Step** and you will observe that,control is converted into a table template which you can see how controls named i.e. UserName,Password...

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server">
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server" ID="CreateUserWizardStep1">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                Sign Up for Your New Account</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

.......
```

Also know that If you wish to find control from inner templates , you must look for templates with `FindControl` method to reach the control you desire.
To Find UserName Control in above code,use

```
CreateUserWizardStep1.TemplateControl.FindControl("UserName") as TextBox
```

Hope this helps to solve your problem

Comment: When using <asp:Login> inside the masterpage, I get no error. When inserting the <asp:login> inside a usercontrol inside an login.ascx, I get this:

UserLogin: LayoutTemplate does not contain an IEditableTextControl with ID UserName for the username.